# What is the legal status of the CIA involved in attacks by Ukraine spies on Russian territory?

Tags: united-states, ukraine, terrorism, cia

According to [WP article from 23 oct 2023](https://www.washingtonpost.com/world/2023/10/23/ukraine-cia-shadow-war-russia/), CIA was involved in  Security Service of Ukraine operations including ones that might not be justified depending on definition of "legal military target", like attack on Kremlin and Dugina killing.

> The August 2022 attack is part of a raging shadow war in which Ukraine’s spy services have also twice bombed the bridge connecting Russia to occupied Crimea, piloted drones into the roof of the Kremlin and blown holes in the hulls of Russian naval vessels in the Black Sea.

> The missions have involved elite teams of Ukrainian operatives drawn from directorates that were formed, trained and equipped in close partnership with the CIA, according to current and former Ukrainian and U.S. officials.

From the same article:

> The extent of the CIA’s involvement with Ukraine’s security services
> has not previously been disclosed. U.S. intelligence officials
> stressed that the agency has had no involvement in targeted killing
> operations by Ukrainian agencies, and that its work has focused on
> bolstering those services’ abilities to gather intelligence on a
> dangerous adversary. A senior intelligence official said that “any
> potential operational concerns have been conveyed clearly to the
> Ukrainian services.”

On the other hand, "plausible deniability" is a thing, and CIA had been previously caught on performing morally dubious operations, prompting creation of congressional oversight committees for intelligence agencies. How is CIA activity currently controlled? Would the President of the US (or other US officials) be informed of these operations, and at what stage (in other words, could oversight block an operation because their permission is needed, or would they be informed post-factum)? To what extent CIA collaborates with SBU, and in these cases specifically?

Comment: A neutral-worded question is more likely to attract answers from people who would otherwise perceive any answer as acknowledgement of a position they do not support. As a consequence, it is also a sign of a good-faith effort to receive an actual answer (as opposed to an attempt to promote one's viewpoint). In this case - you'd have to focus on your questions about CIA, or risk answerers focusing on whether SBU actions can be classified as terrorism or not. I have edited the question with this in mind, roll back if I understood your intention wrong.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov what kind of a neutral-warded do you mean? How can i name the act of the civil killing by the spies? The problem also that the article is not ever neutral, you know)? And it's words singed contradictory also, like : CIA don't involved but they do). OR: CIA said that they are not involved, but they do some atleast and there is no any of conformation that they are not do...

Comment: @άνθρωπος the term ["targeted killing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Targeted_killing) is commonly used. Regarding the article - I think it's fine to quote a biased source. It's just an author's opinion, clarification on which you are asking. It doesn't affect the answerer in the way supplying your own opinion in the question does.

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov but "targeted killing" is about drone killing. Also this: "Some academics, military personnel and officials[6] describe targeted killing as legitimate within the context of self-defense, when employed against terrorists or combatants engaged in asymmetrical warfare. " But Russian territory is not involved as US said. Also civils are not a combatants. I think this term is not right. And the main question what is the degree of the CIA involvement in this process?

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov But it is okey, you can change the question as you need, i hope you are understanding what you do, when you are choosing such words or neutrals) Thanks for fixing.

Comment: @άνθρωπος yeah, that whole paragraph makes ithe definition kind of hard to understand, but it actually refers to the (disputed) moral ambiguity of a very specific scenario (US drone strikes during War on Terror). But from the examples in the article, it is clear that "targeted killing" is used to describe any killing of a specific person (as opposed to indiscriminate mass murder) by a state or organisation, regardless of their status or the tools used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149304/discussion-between--and-danila-smirnov).

Answer (score 3):

Not getting into the rights or wrongs of GUR actions.  Or CIA involvement with GUR lethal actions.  Nor is it reasonable to expect the community to know about *secret* CIA-GUR links.

But as far as who oversees the CIA, [this](https://irp.fas.org/cia/product/facttell/legover.htm) seems a reasonable synopsis:

> Following allegations of wrongdoing by US intelligence agencies, the Senate established the Senate Select Committee on Intelligence (SSCI) on 19 May 1976. The House of Representatives followed suit on 14 July 1977 by creating the House Permanent Select Committee on Intelligence (HPSCI). These committees, along with the Armed Services as well as the Foreign Relations and Foreign Affairs Committees, were charged with authorizing the programs of the intelligence agencies and overseeing their activities.
>
> The 1980 Intelligence Oversight Act established the current oversight structure by making SSCI and HPSCI the only two oversight committees for the CIA. However, the Appropriations Committees, given their constitutional role to appropriate funds for all US Government activities, also exercise some oversight functions. In addition, the CIA interacts closely with other committees, depending on issues and jurisdiction.

More on [genesis](https://www.cnas.org/publications/reports/enhancing-congressional-intelligence-committee-effectiveness):

> The Senate Select Committee on Intelligence and House Permanent Select Committee on Intelligence were created in 1976 and 1977, respectively. The committees were created as a result of substantial exposure of intelligence community abuses after the Watergate era.

So, yes, there is oversight.  And, no, unlikely they'd care overmuch about *indirect* CIA involvement wrt *most* actions in the question `*`.  Ukraine is, obviously, rather well supported by the US, so providing spy training is rather tame in comparison.  And the US did disavow the Dugina hit so there's no great reason to suspect *direct* CIA involvement.  GUR is probably going to keep CIA at arms length about their more "questionable", non-military, activities and the CIA will likely avoid asking or getting involved.

Last, since the question asked about POTUS/Joe Biden knowledge, **if** the CIA was indeed doing something that was liable to upset their congressional overseers, then there would likely be some ["Will no one rid me of this turbulent priest?"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_no_one_rid_me_of_this_turbulent_priest) going-ons to bring plausible deniability to POTUS having given the green light personally.  That's what happened with Reagan's Iran Contra Affair and Mitterand's Rainbow Warrior, with someone really senior taking the blame instead.

`*` Direct kinetic action by CIA operatives in Russia would most likely land the CIA in really hot water.

Comment: Which is a bit implausible in this case. I bet Biden can't answer who Dugin is, if you ask him the first thing in the morning. Also, the US clearly doesn't even want to be publicly tied even to the [later] Kerch bridge attacks with missiles, which were instead supplied by the UK.

Comment: Actually, even that I'm not sure it's confirmed. Russia [claimed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zF24f4i_0MU) it was a Storm Shadow, but the UK press [said](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-12305599/Major-double-strike-hits-Putins-3billion-bridge-linking-Russia-illegally-annexed-Crimea.html) it was a drone. OTOH [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShwmjKYj7JU) ain't no drone, so maybe those were different events.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**: This is the early answer remaining from the time when the question has been framed around the assistance with "terroristic acts". The question has been edited since.

Pro Russian propaganda even [names](https://www.nbcnews.com/news/world/ukraine-drone-attacks-russia-military-planes-damaged-pskov-rcna102496) drone strikes over they military airports, from where bombers take off to launch rockets over Ukraine - even these are named "terrorism". With definitions so extremely wide (about anything inside Russia), for sure.

While USA disallows using the major delivered weapons over Russians territory, it does [provide](https://www.defense.gov/News/News-Stories/Article/Article/3248075/us-plans-combined-arms-training-for-ukrainian-soldiers/) military training for Ukraine, and the acquired skills can be used in places like Crimea or also the Russian territory. Striking into the territory of the country at war it is generally not seen as terrorism, even if Russian PRs do tend to name it so.

Speaking about Kremlin, it is a military fortress, at least deciding from the name. It can be seen as military headquarters. Speaking about Dugina, it is currently not obvious that she was the intended target, the military value seems not so big.

Comment: This question is the propaganda question. I have nothing against deleting it,

Comment: Your answer is not relate to the question and it's themes. You can change the question also, if you need  it. i d used only the  info from WP in it. Where is propaganda? OR WP is a propaganda press?

Comment: "it does provide military training for Ukraine" - ye, that is it, but there are an official documentation and permissions of the president and Congress on this actions of the military ministry, but what about CIA? What is the legal status of it's involving? As i know they also need permition from the president. And also this actins is more close to open war, or not?

Answer (score 1):

> To what extent CIA collaborates with SBU, and in these cases specifically?

From the piece itself

> This article is based on interviews with more than two dozen current and former Ukrainian, U.S. and Western intelligence and security officials who spoke on the condition of anonymity citing security concerns as well as the sensitivity of the subject. The CIA declined to comment. [...]
>
> “We had a lot of restrictions about working with the Ukrainians operationally,” said a former U.S. intelligence official. The emphasis was “more on secure communications and tradecraft,” and pursuing new streams of intelligence inside Russia “rather than ‘here’s how you blow up a mayor.’ I never got the sense that we were that involved in designing their ops.”

And to summarize the [very] long piece: US intelligence apparently knew about the planned attack on the bridge beforehand and "registered concerns". But there's no acknowledgement/details given at all what they might have known [if anything] about the attack on Dugin[a] beforehand. If there's anything plausibly related in the piece:

> “There were some things that maybe we wouldn’t talk about” with CIA counterparts, said a second Ukraine security official involved in such missions. He said crossing those boundaries would lead to a terse reply from Americans: “We don’t want any part of that.”